# Paste text in Edit Text from an SMS automatically in Huawei

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, huawei-mobile-services

I have a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` and reads code from an SMS and pastes it automatically in an `EditText` , this works perfectly on **Samsung** and **Nexus Emulator**, but now it's not working on ***Huawei*** , it does copy the text.. but then user needs to paste it **manually**..

This is my code:

```
public class SimpleSmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) Objects.requireNonNull(pudsBundle).get("pdus");
        String format = pudsBundle.getString("format");
        SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) Objects.requireNonNull(pdus)[0],format);

       // check if sender is specificSender
        if(messages.getOriginatingAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("specificSender")) {
            // get only the numbers from the sms
            String number = messages.getMessageBody().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

            // place the code in the edit text
            if(VerifyActivity.isVerifyRunning) {
                VerifyActivity.et_code.setText(number);
            } else if(BaseActivity.isChangeNumberOn)
            {
                EditText et = BaseActivity.changeNumber.findViewById(R.id.et_code);
                et.setText(number);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea what might cause this?

> is it related to Huawei devices or is there something I should add to my
>   code?

Thank You.

Comment: add your code please

Comment: ok I added it..